# Creating an R function that can accept both datasets and object names as well as those names as a string object

Tags: r, rlang

I can make a function that takes object names as arguments (this is just a normal function).

I can also now make a function that get's its data and column arguments via a named vector (utilising `dataset <- eval(sym(dataset))` and `date_col <- sym(date_col)`).

However I would like a function that can handle both types of inputs.

Step one is to detect the class of the input.

For the dataset argument, this (below) works fine for both the named vector and the actual object name.

```
 if (is.character(dataset)) {
    dataset <- eval(sym(dataset)) }
```

I am not able to figure out the appropriate way to handle the column arguments, however.

When I use the named-vector elements for them, the process (below) works fine.

```
  if (is.character(date_col)) {
    date_col <- sym(date_col) }
```

But I am unsure how to handle the actual column name (ie by adding in an `else` component, above).
Essentially I want to turn it into a sym so I can still use the {{}} (or !!) in the function's steps.

Here is a minimum reproducible example for what I am after.
As you will see the named vector version works but not the actual dataset and column names.

Is what I'm after even possible? Can a function be dynamic in this way or do I need to make two separate functions?

[edited: made a simpler example, as per comment]

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)


new_table <- tibble(
  Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), 1)) %>% 
  mutate(total_sales = rnorm(n()))


f_arguments <- c("dataset" = "new_table",
                        "date_col" = "Date",
                        "sales_col" = "total_sales")


f <- function(data, x, envir = parent.frame()) {

  if (is.character(data)) {
    data <- get(data, envir)}


  if (is.character(x)) {
    x <- sym(x) }

  data %>% 
    mutate(year_month = lubridate::floor_date(!!ensym(x), "months"),
           year = lubridate::year(!!ensym(x)))

}


# this (below) works per the above code, but not if I comment out 
# the if (is.character(x)) line

f(f_arguments[["dataset"]], 
  f_arguments[["date_col"]])


# this (below) does not work with the above code, but it will work if I comment out 
# the if (is.character(x)) line

f(new_table, Date)
```

Comment: ps, have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376099/accept-both-bare-from-rlang-or-string-as-a-function-input and non of their solutions seem to work, for my example

Comment: Questions should have *minimal* examples as per instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. There is a lot of code above  that is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Have updated to get a simpler minimal example

Answer (score 1):

Have revised the example in line with the revised question.

```
library(dplr)
library(lubridate)

f <- function(data, x, envir = parent.frame()) {
  if (is.character(data)) data <- get(data, envir)
  x <- eval(substitute(x), data, envir)
  if (is.character(x)) x <- data[[x]]
  data %>% mutate(year = year(x)) %>% slice(1:2)
}
```

giving

```
f(f_arguments[["dataset"]], f_arguments[["date_col"]])  # test 1
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   Date       total_sales  year
##   <date>           <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01      -0.975  2016
## 2 2016-01-02       0.120  2016

f("new_table", "Date") # test 2
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   Date       total_sales  year
##   <date>           <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01      -0.975  2016
## 2 2016-01-02       0.120  2016

f(new_table, Date)  # test 3
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   Date       total_sales  year
##   <date>           <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01      -0.975  2016
## 2 2016-01-02       0.120  2016

f(new_table, f_arguments[["date_col"]]) # test 4
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   Date       total_sales  year
##   <date>           <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01      -0.975  2016
## 2 2016-01-02       0.120  2016

# test 5
g <- function(...) { new_tab <- new_table; f(...) }
g("new_tab", "Date") 
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   Date       total_sales  year
##   <date>           <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01      -0.975  2016
## 2 2016-01-02       0.120  2016
```

### Note

Personally I would not do the above and would avoid unevaluated arguments and would pass the first argument as an object and the second as a character string.  The two examples shown below would still work.

```
f2 <- function(data, x) {
  data %>% mutate(year = year(.[[x]])) %>% slice(1:2)
}

f2(new_table, "Date")
f2(get(f_arguments[["dataset"]]), f_arguments[["date_col"]])
```

Alternately allow data to be passed as a character string using S3:

```
f3 <- function(data, x, ...) UseMethod("f3")
f3.default <- function(data, x, ...)  {
  data %>% mutate(year = year(.[[x]])) %>% slice(1:2)
}
f3.character <- function(data, x, envir = parent.frame(), ...) {
   data <- get(data, envir)
   NextMethod()
}

f3(new_table, "Date")
f3(f_arguments[["dataset"]], f_arguments[["date_col"]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Grothendieck, your code works for your example but not for mine. I have simplified my initial example. I cannot figure out the critical difference. Any hints as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Have revised the example to be closer to the revised question.

Comment: thanks @G.Grotherndieck, have posted an answer to my own question (is this not the done thing?). Certainly your responses guided me heaps... But I'm thinking my new function is simpler... what do you reckon? I don't quite understand what your parent.frame() argument does in your example.. but most of rlang is a mystery to me... currently in the phase of going with what works rather than solidifying an overarching understanding (hopefully that comes later).

Comment: The `parent.frame()` code is to address situations such as test 5 where the data frame is not in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to have a function that can accept either "stringed" arguments or the regular dataset and column references. And to do this with minimal alterations to the original function.

ie, it will take `"data"` as well as just `data`. And `"column_x"` as well as the regular `column_x`.

The challenge is that you need to include rlang `!!` in the function in order for the 
"stringed" values to work but this prevents the regular argument versions.

The following solution detects whether the first (dataset) argument is a string or not and then applies the correct transformations to the arguments, so that the function can proceed, using the rlang `!!`.

```
f <- function(data, column_x) {

  if (is.character(data)) {
    data <- eval(sym(data))
    column_x <- sym(column_x) }

  data %>% 
    mutate(year_month = lubridate::floor_date(!! ensym(column_x), "months"),
           year = lubridate::year(!! ensym(column_x))) %>% 
    head(2)
}


# let's test

f(f_arguments[["dataset"]], 
  f_arguments[["date_col"]])


f(new_table, Date)
```

I certainly wouldn't have been able to get to this without the generous assistance of @G.Grothendieck and @andrew_reece (from my previous question).

Comment: This code gives errors when run with tests 4 and 5 in my answer.